# Dependency library not recognized during installation octave forge dicom package in debian linux

Tags: linux, package, debian, octave, gdcm

I ask this question on this stack exchange because it has (by far) the most posts about octave.

I started using a linux environment and want to use octave for my work, for which the [dicom package](http://wiki.octave.org/Dicom_package) is essential (my data is in the dicom format and not readily converted to nifti because of its high dimensionality, it would require many,many seperate files).

The dicom package is dependend on the [gdcm](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gdcm/) library, which I have installed. The when installing the dicom package I get this error:

fatal error: gdcm-2.0/gdcmReader.h: No such file

The current gdcm version is newer than 2.0 so I thought maybe I should use the older version, but the error remained. Even the older function did not get installed to that path. I think the dicom package does not look at which path it should use.

Maybe this is a bug because the path is hardcoded (as suggested in the similar OSx thread)
Maybe this happens because the last release is from 2011 and the package is just not maintained anymore, while gdcm keeps getting updates.
Maybe Im just doing something horribly wrong that Im not seeing.

Comment: The best place to ask this would be the Octave mailing list. Take a look at the development repo of the dicom package which has a configure.ac file and a new Makefile (which is generated by configure).

Comment: Thanks Ill also send it to that list. I also found a page where you can report bugs, Ill do that too. the configure.ac file is a good hint. Ill have a look at that too.

Comment: Do not report a bug, it is already fixed (I fixed it some months ago). Check the dicom package repository if you want. But do ask the help mailing list for help.

Comment: Ok I already reported it, Ill see if I can retract that.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `gdcm-2.0/gdcmReader.h` with `gdcm-2.4/gdcmReader.h` in the octave binding.

Comment: Ah thanks. How do I do that? I used the pkg command inside octave. For your solution I need to download the tar file probably. Which file inside the tar contains the octave binding that I should change then?

Comment: Use `grep gdcm-2.0 *` to find them all.

Comment: This will not fix all the problems in octave. See this thread for more details. http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/Can-t-install-dicom-package-0-1-1-and-0-1-2-user-version-in-octave-4-0-2-and-ubuntu-14-0-td4681648.html